# 419 unknown status in Laravel 5.6 with reactJs

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-native, laravel-5.6

I have implemented Reactjs with in Laravel 5.6. I have faced a error(419 unknown status) when i submitted a form.

Scripting ::

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const products = {
    title: this.state.title,
    body: this.state.body
  }
  let uri = MyGlobleSetting.url + '/products/'+this.props.params.id;
  axios.post(uri, products).then((response) => {
        //this.props.history.push('/display-item');
        browserHistory.push('/display-item');
  });
}
```

Route ::

```
Route::post('products/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@update'
```

]);

Controller ::

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->title = $request->get('title');
    $product->body = $request->get('body');
    $product->save();

    return response()->json('Product Updated Successfully.');
}
```

Let me suggest what i mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Add meta tag with csrf token in your layout file and then add csrf token in `axios` header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**in app.js or your main js file** (add token to axios header)

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```